# IMAP Mail Server that works with Active Directory? Exchange?

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, exchange-2010

I have a small AD Domain running on Win2008 R2. I have several e-Mail accounts with a Provider.

What I would like is to have a Mail Server in my Domain that picks up the mail from my Provider (POP3), stores them locally and makes them accessible to a domain user through IMAP (so that I can access it on multiple machines). Sending mail should go from my Client to my Server and them to the providers SMTP.

I'd like to integrate with my exising Active Directory users, so that my IMAP Usernames/Password are the same always as the AD User. Also, it should behave "friendly" towards the Windows Backup, so no "can't backup as files are in use"

Can Exchange 2010 do that? Or is there another Mail Server that does that? I don't need fancy stuff like public folders and the like.

Comment: Exchange does include an IMAP service, but paying for Exchange just for IMAP would be a little silly, since there's so much more to the product. You don't buy a Ferrari just because you like its sound equipment. ;-) Having said that, I don't know if there are any other IMAP-only products which fulfil your requirements, which is why I'm making this a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Graeme Thanks. Licensing is not so much the issue, it's more about finding the right tool - low maintenance, simple to setup and well-integrated.

Comment: Have you considered simply switching to an alternate email provider?  Microsoft, or Google both have good offerings.

Comment: @zoredache No, my mail provider is the one of my domain (stum.de), I'm not switching away from that :) Also, I want to have my mail archive locally, not in the cloud.

Comment: even ignoring the upfront licensing cost, the cost of maintaining an Exchange server isn't trivial, and if you only need IMAP, I can't see that it is justifiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if hMailServer ([Official site](http://www.hmailserver.com/) / [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMailServer)) would serve your needs perfectly.

It uses a database to store its own configuration and mail index data. This could be backed up using the standard tools provided by your DB engine of choice.

Mail data, i.e. the actual email messages, is stored as raw MIME format, i.e. plain text and you should have no issues making backups of that.

It has AD integration so that your users don't need to remember yet another password.

Comment: It was a bit weird to setup, but it works fine, thanks!